# Cannot call CREATE SCHEMA through JDBC in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm using the official SQL Server JDBC driver:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

To run this code here:

```java
try (Connection c = new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver().connect(u, p)) {
    try (PreparedStatement s1 = c.prepareStatement("create schema x");
         PreparedStatement s2 = c.prepareStatement("drop schema x")) {
        System.out.println(s1.execute());
        System.out.println(s2.execute());
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'schema'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1547)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:528)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:461)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2689)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:224)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:204)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:445)
```

Obviuosly, the statements are correct and they work as static statements:

```
try (Statement s1 = c.createStatement();
     Statement s2 = c.createStatement()) {
    System.out.println(s1.execute("create schema x"));
    System.out.println(s2.execute("drop schema x"));
}
```

Is this intended, or a bug in the JDBC driver?

Comment: Not my DV, seems like a reasonable QA. I'm curious why it's failing though, can you profile the SQL and see exactly what is being sent to SQL Server?

Comment: @DavidG: Not too well acquainted with SQL Server tooling. I haven't seen any messages in the trace file of the log directory. Debugging through the JDBC driver doesn't show anything unusual with the statement string itself. Of course, I don't know much about the protocol bytes that are sent to the server...

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, Tools menu, SQL Server Profiler. It lets you see what SQL commands are being sent over. May not show anything in this case if the driver is getting in the way, but the exception message seems to suggest it's coming from the SQL engine. Of course, I don't think there's much benefit to a prepared statement for creating schemas and views :)

Comment: @DavidG: Oh, very interesting, thanks. I started the profiler via the trace file, no wonder I didn't see anything interesting. Hmm, the prepared statement version sends this string (in 6.2.0): `exec sp_executesql N'drop schema x', NULL`. Interesting trailing `NULL` parameter. Prior to that (in 6.1.0), there was a more complex batch calling `[...] exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,NULL,N'create schema x' [...]`

Comment: This certainly looks like a side-effect of the performance tweaks in 6.2.0 that evolved out of [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/166).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a regression in version 6.2.0. It used to work in version 6.1.0. I've reported this issue to Microsoft: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/370

The `CREATE VIEW` statement is also affected:

```java
// Works on both versions 6.2.0 and 6.1.0
try (Statement s1 = c.createStatement();
     Statement s2 = c.createStatement()) {
    System.out.println(s1.execute("create view x as select 1 a"));
    System.out.println(s2.execute("drop view x"));
}

// Works only on version 6.1.0
try (PreparedStatement s1 = c.prepareStatement("create view x as select 1 a");
     PreparedStatement s2 = c.prepareStatement("drop view x")) {
    System.out.println(s1.execute());
    System.out.println(s2.execute());
}
```

(I'm documenting this here on Stack Overflow because several tools that run DDL, including jOOQ, Hibernate, MyBatis, Flyway, etc. might be affected)